# Tweepy streaming returns 401 Authorization Required

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy, twython

I am trying to connect to the twitter stream api to fetch tweets in realtime. This piece of code was working till 5-6 ago. Suddenly I've started receiving 401 all the time. Strangely this is both happening in my local machine and on our production server which is located in cloud, so I think this is not a network related issue.

Here is the code:

```
l = StdOutListener()

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth.callback = 'https://localhost' #no effect commented/uncommented
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=['twitter'], languages=["es"])
```

So far I've tried the following:

1. Generating new consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access token secret. I've used 4 different set of keys which was working previously.
2. Created a fresh new app from apps.twitter.com. Filled the callback url as some users reported that 401 "Authorization Required" is related with the callback URL field missing in the application page of twitter.
3. Synced my clock with an ntp server, both on my local and on production server. My clock is not off.
4. My application have the correct privileges and I received access token and secret after the configuration.

Here is the request:

```
'Content-Length': '22'
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="161484371946745487981492681844"
    oauth_timestamp="1492681844"
    oauth_version="1.0"
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"
    oauth_consumer_key="<oauth_consumer_key>"
    oauth_token="<oauth_token>"
    oauth_signature="tphQqFWaBvEo2byjZ%2BRqNAM30I0%3D"'
Method: 'POST'
URL: 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length'
```

Any help would be appreciated on why I am getting a 401 Unauthorized "Need Authorization" response.

Edit: I've also tried using Twython and I got the same response back from twitter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue after 2 weeks of troubleshooting. For tweepy you need to manually set the callback url of the auth object you use to authenticate with the twitter.

After this correction head to apps.twitter.com and uncheck the box "Allow this application to to be used to Sign in with Twitter". Twitter API is not concise at all with the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using Twython OAuth2 to connect if you don't need to tweet back
[Twython Auth](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html)

Or try using this code.

```
# Put the consumer keys
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_key", "consumer_secret")

# Redirect user to Twitter to authorize
redirect_user(auth.get_authorization_url())

# Get access token
auth.get_access_token("verifier_value")

# Construct the API instance
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Create the stream
streamClass= StdOutListener()
stream= tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=streamClass)
```

This should work. 
Maybe your bot is not authorised on the account and this may be the error. But I don't think it's the case.

Check out my BOT's auth if you want an example : 
[ED_Postcards BOT](https://github.com/Foxlider/EDPostcards_BOT/blob/beta/EDPostcards.py)
(New version incoming with pretty code)

Comment: Same with twython Oauth too. Also you don't need Oauth2 to connect to stream endpoint.

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of tweepy ?